# ASP.NET mvc1 template for VS.net 2010?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

As the title says, is there a MVC1 template for vs.net 2010?

For various reasons, we cant upgrade to mvc2 (or .net framework v4) just quite yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can trick Visual Studio 2010 in believing that your ASP.NET MVC1 project is actually using ASP.NET MVC 2. You can run the upgrade wizard and then change the assembly reference to ASP.NET MVC 1 and update the assembly versions in the web.config (from 2.0.0.0 to 1.0.0.0).

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such a template but if you have an existing ASP.NET MVC 1.0 project you could open it in Visual Studio 2010 and it should work as long as you have the assemblies installed in the GAC.